# How to add CheckBox's to a TableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, checkbox, tableview, tablecell, javafx-2

In my Java Desktop Application I have a TableView in which I want to have a column with CheckBoxes.

I did find where this has been done on Jonathan Giles's website http://www.jonathangiles.net (the page where this was published in 2011 is no longer active so I removed the old link from the post), However, the download is not available and Jonathan Giles did not answer my email, so I thought I'd ask...

How do I put a CheckBox in a cell of my TableView?

Comment: Your reference link is dead, please update it

Comment: The link has been removed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to set a CellFactory on the TableColumn.

For example:

```
Callback<TableColumn<TableData, Boolean>, TableCell<TableData, Boolean>> booleanCellFactory = 
            new Callback<TableColumn<TableData, Boolean>, TableCell<TableData, Boolean>>() {
            @Override
                public TableCell<TableData, Boolean> call(TableColumn<TableData, Boolean> p) {
                    return new BooleanCell();
            }
        };
        active.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,Boolean>("active"));
        active.setCellFactory(booleanCellFactory);

class BooleanCell extends TableCell<TableData, Boolean> {
        private CheckBox checkBox;
        public BooleanCell() {
            checkBox = new CheckBox();
            checkBox.setDisable(true);
            checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean> () {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    if(isEditing())
                        commitEdit(newValue == null ? false : newValue);
                }
            });
            this.setGraphic(checkBox);
            this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            this.setEditable(true);
        }
        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();
            if (isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            checkBox.setDisable(false);
            checkBox.requestFocus();
        }
        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            checkBox.setDisable(true);
        }
        public void commitEdit(Boolean value) {
            super.commitEdit(value);
            checkBox.setDisable(true);
        }
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                checkBox.setSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I already figured this one out. This is not how I did it but it probably works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is not the recommended way with Java FX 2.2+ - cf other answers.

Comment: @assylias. Can you clarify and materialize your comment? You meant CheckBoxTableCell?

Comment: @UlukBiy Yes - which was probably not available when this answer was written. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @assylias. No. Most new starters may not know the CheckBoxTableCell was added in later version, that's why "clarify". You may found/wrote some good comparative article on recommended way, that's why "materialize".

Comment: @UlukBiy Understood - I have added an answer.

Answer (score 59):

Uses [`javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell<S,T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html) and the work's done !

```
  ObservableList< TableColumn< RSSReader, ? >> columns =
     _rssStreamsView.getColumns();
  [...]
  TableColumn< RSSReader, Boolean > loadedColumn = new TableColumn<>( "Loaded" );
  loadedColumn.setCellValueFactory(
    new Callback<CellDataFeatures<RSSReader,Boolean>,ObservableValue<Boolean>>(){
        @Override public
        ObservableValue<Boolean> call( CellDataFeatures<RSSReader,Boolean> p ){
           return p.getValue().getCompleted(); }});
  loadedColumn.setCellFactory(
     new Callback<TableColumn<RSSReader,Boolean>,TableCell<RSSReader,Boolean>>(){
        @Override public
        TableCell<RSSReader,Boolean> call( TableColumn<RSSReader,Boolean> p ){
           return new CheckBoxTableCell<>(); }});
  [...]
  columns.add( loadedColumn );
```

**UPDATE:** same code using [Java 8 lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

```
  ObservableList< TableColumn< RSSReader, ? >> columns =
     _rssStreamsView.getColumns();
  [...]
  TableColumn< RSSReader, Boolean > loadedColumn = new TableColumn<>( "Loaded" );
  loadedColumn.setCellValueFactory( f -> f.getValue().getCompleted());
  loadedColumn.setCellFactory( tc -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());
  [...]
  columns.add( loadedColumn );
```

Lines count is divided by two! (16 ==> 8)

**UPDATE:** same code using [Java 10 "var" contextual word](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286)

```
  var columns = _rssStreamsView.getColumns();
  [...]
  var loadedColumn = new TableColumn<RSSReader, Boolean>( "Loaded" );
  loadedColumn.setCellValueFactory( f -> f.getValue().getCompleted());
  loadedColumn.setCellFactory( tc -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());
  [...]
  columns.add( loadedColumn );
```

**EDIT to add full functional editable example (Java 8)**

```
public class Os {

   private final StringProperty  name   = new SimpleStringProperty();
   private final BooleanProperty delete = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

   public Os( String nm, boolean del ) {
      name  .set( nm  );
      delete.set( del );
   }

   public StringProperty  nameProperty  () { return name;   }
   public BooleanProperty deleteProperty() { return delete; }
}

public class FxEditableCheckBox extends Application {

   @Override
   public void start( Stage stage ) throws Exception {
      final TableView<Os> view = new TableView<>();
      final ObservableList<TableColumn<Os, ?>> columns = view.getColumns();

      final TableColumn<Os, Boolean> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>( "Name" );
      nameColumn.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>( "name" ));
      columns.add(  nameColumn );

      final TableColumn<Os, Boolean> loadedColumn = new TableColumn<>( "Delete" );
      loadedColumn.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>( "delete" ));
      loadedColumn.setCellFactory( tc -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());
      columns.add( loadedColumn );

      final ObservableList<Os> items =
         FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Os( "Microsoft Windows 3.1"    , true  ),
            new Os( "Microsoft Windows 3.11"   , true  ),
            new Os( "Microsoft Windows 95"     , true  ),
            new Os( "Microsoft Windows NT 3.51", true  ),
            new Os( "Microsoft Windows NT 4"   , true  ),
            new Os( "Microsoft Windows 2000"   , true  ),
            new Os( "Microsoft Windows Vista"  , true  ),
            new Os( "Microsoft Windows Seven"  , false ),
            new Os( "Linux all versions :-)"   , false ));
      view.setItems( items );
      view.setEditable( true );

      final Button delBtn = new Button( "Delete" );
      delBtn.setMaxWidth( Double.MAX_VALUE );
      delBtn.setOnAction( e -> {
         final Set<Os> del = new HashSet<>();
         for( final Os os : view.getItems()) {
            if( os.deleteProperty().get()) {
               del.add( os );
            }
         }
         view.getItems().removeAll( del );
      });
      stage.setScene( new Scene( new BorderPane( view, null, null, delBtn, null )));
      BorderPane.setAlignment( delBtn, Pos.CENTER );
      stage.show();
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      launch( args );
   }
}
```

**EDIT to add full functional editable example (Java 10)**

```
public class Os {

   private final StringProperty  name   = new SimpleStringProperty();
   private final BooleanProperty delete = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

   public Os( String nm, boolean del ) {
      name  .set( nm  );
      delete.set( del );
   }

   public StringProperty  nameProperty  () { return name;   }
   public BooleanProperty deleteProperty() { return delete; }
}

public class FxEditableCheckBoxJava10 extends Application {

   @Override
   public void start( Stage stage ) throws Exception {
      final var view       = new TableView<Os>();
      final var columns    = view.getColumns();
      final var nameColumn = new TableColumn<Os, Boolean>( "Name" );
      nameColumn.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>( "name" ));
      columns.add(  nameColumn );
      final var loadedColumn = new TableColumn<Os, Boolean>( "Delete" );
      loadedColumn.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>( "delete" ));
      loadedColumn.setCellFactory( tc -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());
      columns.add( loadedColumn );
      final var items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
         new Os( "Microsoft Windows 3.1"    , true  ),
         new Os( "Microsoft Windows 3.11"   , true  ),
         new Os( "Microsoft Windows 95"     , true  ),
         new Os( "Microsoft Windows NT 3.51", true  ),
         new Os( "Microsoft Windows NT 4"   , true  ),
         new Os( "Microsoft Windows 2000"   , true  ),
         new Os( "Microsoft Windows Vista"  , true  ),
         new Os( "Microsoft Windows Seven"  , false ),
         new Os( "Linux all versions :-)"   , false ));
      view.setItems( items );
      view.setEditable( true );
      final var delBtn = new Button( "Delete" );
      delBtn.setMaxWidth( Double.MAX_VALUE );
      delBtn.setOnAction( e -> {
         final var del = new HashSet<Os>();
         for( final var os : view.getItems()) {
            if( os.deleteProperty().get()) {
               del.add( os );
            }
         }
         view.getItems().removeAll( del );
      });
      stage.setScene( new Scene( new BorderPane( view, null, null, delBtn, null )));
      BorderPane.setAlignment( delBtn, Pos.CENTER );
      stage.show();
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      launch( args );
   }
}
```

Comment: Using this code, the checkbox column is added but they don't respond to clicks (check doesn't change).

Comment: Using `setEditable(true);` doesn't do anything, either.

Comment: A table doesn't become editable only with `setEditable`. Columns may be editable and the underlying model must be set to be editable. It's another problem, another post. Please build a new post with a full featured question about editable JavaFX tables.

Comment: Isn't the point of a checkbox to be able to check and uncheck it?

Comment: No, a checkbox may be used as a viewer of an internal state. It may be an editor too.

Answer (score 17):

```
TableColumn select = new TableColumn("CheckBox");
        select.setMinWidth(200);
        select.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, CheckBox>, ObservableValue<CheckBox>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<CheckBox> call(
                    TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, CheckBox> arg0) {
                Person user = arg0.getValue();

                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();

                checkBox.selectedProperty().setValue(user.isSelected());



                checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov,
                            Boolean old_val, Boolean new_val) {

                        user.setSelected(new_val);

                    }
                });

                return new SimpleObjectProperty<CheckBox>(checkBox);

            }

        });
        table.getColumns().addAll( select);
```

Comment: Working as expected :)

Comment: Perfect :) simple and perfect

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! this is the only solution that worked.

Answer (score 12):

Small and simple.

```html
row.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleBooleanProperty(c.getValue().getIsDefault()));
row.setCellFactory(tc -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());
```

Comment: Love it! :-) clean and simple

Comment: Not clean. What is getIsDefault

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution is probably to do it in FXML:

1. First create the class below:

   ```
   public class CheckBoxCellFactory<S, T>
             implements Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> {
       @Override public TableCell<S, T> call(TableColumn<S, T> p) {
           return new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then include a cell factory in your FXML:

   ```
   <TableColumn text="Select" fx:id="selectColumn" >
       <cellFactory>
           <CheckBoxCellFactory/>
       </cellFactory>
   </TableColumn>
   ```

You also need to add an import in the FXML, such as `<?import com.assylias.factories.*?>`

---

Bonus: you can make the factory more customisable, for example to determine where the checkbox should appear, by adding fields to the `CheckBoxCellFactory` class, such as:

```
private Pos alignment = Pos.CENTER;
public Pos getAlignment() { return alignment; }
public void setAlignment(Pos alignment) { this.alignment = alignment; }
```

And the FXML:

```
<cellFactory>
    <CheckBoxCellFactory alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT"/>
</cellFactory>
```

Comment: But the most important is, how to check if some row has the checkbox "checked"?

Answer (score 7):

There is a very simple way of doing this, you don't need to modify your model class with SimpleBooleanProperty or whatever, just follow these steps:

**1 - Suppose you have a "Person" object with a isUnemployed method:**

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Boolean unemployed;

    public String getName(){return this.name;}
    public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}
    public Boolean isUnemployed(){return this.unemployed;}
    public void setUnemployed(Boolean unemployed){this.unemployed = unemployed;}
}
```

**2 - Create the callback class**

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class PersonUnemployedValueFactory implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, CheckBox>, ObservableValue<CheckBox>> {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<CheckBox> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, CheckBox> param) {
        Person person = param.getValue();
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.selectedProperty().setValue(person.isUnemployed());
        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((ov, old_val, new_val) -> {
            person.setUnemployed(new_val);
        });
        return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(checkBox);
    }
}
```

**3 - Bind the callback to the table column**

***If you use FXML, put the callback class inside your column:***

```
<TableView fx:id="personList" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="196.0" text="Unemployed">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PersonUnemployedValueFactory/> <!--This is how the magic happens-->
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>

        ...
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

Don't forget to import the class in your FXML:

```
<?import org.yourcompany.yourapp.util.PersonUnemployedValueFactory?>
```

***Without FXML, do it like this:***

```
TableColumn<Person, CheckBox> column = (TableColumn<Person, CheckBox>) personTable.getColumns().get(0);
column.setCellValueFactory(new PersonUnemployedValueFactory());
```

**4 - That's it**

Everything should work as expected, with the value being set to the backing bean when you click on the checkbox, and the checkbox value correctly being set when you load the items list in your table.

Answer (score 2):

This is what ended up working for me (note that the object in my model is `Candidate` and the checkbox determines whether or not they are excluded, hence `isExcluded()`):

```
tableColumnCandidateExcluded.setCellValueFactory(
    c -> {
      Candidate candidate = c.getValue();
      CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
      checkBox.selectedProperty().setValue(candidate.isExcluded());
      checkBox
          .selectedProperty()
          .addListener((ov, old_val, new_val) -> candidate.setExcluded(new_val));
      return new SimpleObjectProperty(checkBox);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution in order to have an EDITABLE checkbox linked to the model is:

Assuming that you have a `Person` model class with two fields, a "name" string and the "selected" boolean value:

```
public class Person {
    private final SimpleBooleanProperty selected;
    private final SimpleStringProperty name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected.get();
    }

    public SimpleBooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected.set(selected);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }
}
```

All you have to do in the controller is:

```
@FXML private TableColumn<Person, Boolean> checkBoxCol;
@FXML private TableColumn<Person, String> nameCol;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    checkBoxCol.setCellFactory(
        CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(checkBoxCol)
    );
    checkBoxCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("selected")
    );
    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("name")
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete working example showing how to keep the model in sync with the view.....

```
package org.pauquette.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class CheckBoxExample extends Application {
    class BooleanCell extends TableCell<TableData, Boolean> {
        private CheckBox checkBox;

        public BooleanCell() {
            checkBox = new CheckBox();
            checkBox.setDisable(true);
            checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    if (isEditing())
                        commitEdit(newValue == null ? false : newValue);
                }
            });
            this.setGraphic(checkBox);
            this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            this.setEditable(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            checkBox.setDisable(true);
        }

        public void commitEdit(Boolean value) {
            super.commitEdit(value);

            checkBox.setDisable(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();
            if (isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            checkBox.setDisable(false);
            checkBox.requestFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                checkBox.setSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }

    // Pojo class. A Javabean
    public class TableData {
        SimpleBooleanProperty favorite;

        SimpleStringProperty stooge;

        // A javabean typically has a zero arg constructor
        // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/
        public TableData() {
        }

        // but can have others also
        public TableData(String stoogeIn, Boolean favoriteIn) {
            stooge = new SimpleStringProperty(stoogeIn);
            favorite = new SimpleBooleanProperty(favoriteIn);
        }

        /**
         * @return the stooge
         */
        public String getStooge() {
            return stooge.get();
        }

        /**
         * @return the favorite
         */
        public Boolean isFavorite() {
            return favorite.get();
        }

        /**
         * @param favorite
         *            the favorite to set
         */
        public void setFavorite(Boolean favorite) {
            this.favorite.setValue(favorite);
        }

        /**
         * @param stooge
         *            the stooge to set
         */
        public void setStooge(String stooge) {
            this.stooge.setValue(stooge);
        }
    }

    // Model class - The model in mvc
    // Typically a representation of a database or nosql source
    public class TableModel {
        ObservableList<TableData> stooges = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        public TableModel() {
            stooges.add(new TableData("Larry", false));
            stooges.add(new TableData("Moe", true));
            stooges.add(new TableData("Curly", false));
        }

        public String displayModel() {
           StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
           for (TableData stooge : stooges) {
               sb.append(stooge.getStooge() + "=" + stooge.isFavorite() + "|");
           }
           return sb.toString();
        }

        /**
         * @return the stooges
         */
        public ObservableList<TableData> getStooges() {
            return stooges;
        }

        public void updateStooge(TableData dataIn) {
            int index=stooges.indexOf(dataIn);
            stooges.set(index, dataIn);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private TableModel model;

    private TableModel getModel() {
        if (model == null) {
            model = new TableModel();
        }
        return model;

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final VBox view=new VBox(10);
        final TableView<TableData> table = new TableView<>();
        final ObservableList<TableColumn<TableData, ?>> columns = table.getColumns();
        final TableModel model = getModel();

        final TableColumn<TableData, String> stoogeColumn = new TableColumn<>("Stooge");
        stoogeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stooge"));
        columns.add(stoogeColumn);

        final Button showModelButton = new Button("Show me the Model, woo,woo,woo");
        final Label showModelLabel = new Label("Model?  Whats that?");
        showModelButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    showModelLabel.setText(model.displayModel());
                }});


        final TableColumn<TableData, CheckBox> favoriteColumn = new TableColumn<TableData, CheckBox>("Favorite");
        favoriteColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<TableData, CheckBox>, ObservableValue<CheckBox>>() {

                    @Override
                    public ObservableValue<CheckBox> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<TableData, CheckBox> arg0) {
                        TableData data = arg0.getValue();
                        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                        checkBox.selectedProperty().setValue(data.isFavorite());
                        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean old_val,
                                    Boolean new_val) {
                                data.setFavorite(new_val);
                                checkBox.setSelected(new_val);
                                model.updateStooge(data);
                            }
                        });

                        return new SimpleObjectProperty<CheckBox>(checkBox);
                    }

                });
        columns.add(favoriteColumn);
        table.setItems(model.getStooges());
        HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(showModelButton,showModelLabel);
        view.getChildren().add(hbox);
        view.getChildren().add(table);

        Scene scene = new Scene(view, 640, 380);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Only 227 lines to show how to use a checkbox in a table view.   Woo,Woo,Woo.  Nach Nach Nach.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from the previous answers, this is the shortest possible version, I think.

```
checkBoxColumn.setCellValueFactory(c -> {
    c.getValue().booleanProperty().addListener((ch, o, n) -> {
    // do something
    });
    return c.getValue().booleanProperty();
});
checkBoxColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(checkBoxColumn));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way is do it

```
tbcSingleton.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().singletonProperty());
tbcSingleton.setCellFactory( param -> {
    return new TableCell<FXMLController, Boolean>(){
        {
            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        }
        protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty){
            if(!empty && item!=null) {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                cb.setSelected(item);
                cb.setFocusTraversable(false);
                cb.selectedProperty().addListener((obs,old,niu)->listaFXMLController.get(getIndex()).setSingleton(niu));
                setGraphic(cb);
            }else
                setGraphic(null);
        }
    };
});
```

- cb.setFocusTraversable(false) is necesary to prevent focus getting
  stuck on it.
- setGraphic(null) is necesary to erase anything left behind after deleting an item or whenever the source list changes
- cb.selectedProperty().addListener((obs,old,niu)->(your stuff...)); this is where you catch the new value of the CheckBox and do whatever you want with it.

Heres another one with a ToggleGroup and ToggleButtons

```
tbcTipoControlador.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().controllerTypeProperty());
tbcTipoControlador.setCellFactory( param -> {
    return new TableCell<FXMLController, ControllerType>() {
        {
            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        }
        protected void updateItem(ControllerType item, boolean empty){
            if(!empty && item!=null) {
                ToggleButton tbModal = new ToggleButton("Modal");
                tbModal.selectedProperty().addListener((obs,old,niu)->{
                    if(niu)
                        listaFXMLController.get(getIndex()).setControllerType(ControllerType.MODAL);
                });
                tbModal.setSelected(item.equals(ControllerType.MODAL));
                ToggleButton tbPlain = new ToggleButton("Plain");
                tbPlain.selectedProperty().addListener((obs,old,niu)->{
                    if(niu)
                        listaFXMLController.get(getIndex()).setControllerType(ControllerType.PLAIN);
                });
                tbPlain.setSelected(item.equals(ControllerType.PLAIN));
                ToggleButton tbApplication= new ToggleButton("Application");
                tbApplication.selectedProperty().addListener((obs,old,niu)->{
                    if(niu)
                        listaFXMLController.get(getIndex()).setControllerType(ControllerType.APPLICATION);
                });
                tbApplication.setSelected(item.equals(ControllerType.APPLICATION));
                ToggleGroup gp = new ToggleGroup();
                tbModal.setFocusTraversable(false);
                tbPlain.setFocusTraversable(false);
                tbApplication.setFocusTraversable(false);
                tbModal.setPrefWidth(120);
                tbPlain.setPrefWidth(120);
                tbApplication.setPrefWidth(120);
                gp.getToggles().addAll(tbModal,tbPlain,tbApplication);
                HBox hb = new HBox();
                hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                hb.getChildren().addAll(tbModal,tbPlain,tbApplication);
                setGraphic(hb);
            }else
                setGraphic(null);
        }
    };
});
```

I did some test and memory consumption is basically the same as using a ComboBoxTableCell

This is how my little application looks (sry, my main language is Spanish and i build it for personal use)
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Here's a 3rd party lib that will do it http://www.jonathangiles.net/javafx/2.0/CellFactories/docs/api/net/jonathangiles/javafx/control/cell/tableview/CheckBoxTableCell.html

Comment: I did find this lib I just don't see a way to download it to include it in my project. In fact this is exactly what I asked Jonathan Giles for.

Comment: looks like he disabled it while he works on supporting 2.0   http://www.jonathangiles.net/javafx/2.0/CellFactories/

Answer (score -2):

for me, works with this solution:

```
Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> checkboxCellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {

        @Override
        public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
            return new CheckboxCell();
        }
    };
    TableColumn selectColumn = (TableColumn) tbvDatos.getColumns().get(1);
    selectColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("selected"));
    selectColumn.setCellFactory(checkboxCellFactory);
```

and the tableCell:

```
public class CheckboxCell extends TableCell<RowData, Boolean> {
CheckBox checkbox;

@Override
protected void updateItem(Boolean arg0, boolean arg1) {
    super.updateItem(arg0, arg1);
        paintCell();
}

private void paintCell() {
    if (checkbox == null) {
        checkbox = new CheckBox();
        checkbox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov,
                    Boolean old_val, Boolean new_val) {
                setItem(new_val);
                ((RowData)getTableView().getItems().get(getTableRow().getIndex())).setSelected(new_val);
            }
        });
    }
    checkbox.setSelected(getValue());
    setText(null);
    setGraphic(checkbox);
}

private Boolean getValue() {
    return getItem() == null ? false : getItem();
}
}
```

if you dont need to make the checkbox with edit event

Comment: Where did you import RowData from? I'm unable to call .setSelected .