# Add column with checkboxes to a table filled from database in JavaFX 2

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I have my table filled out with data from Postgresql database. Now I want to add extra column with checkboxes so that user can check a row and delete it. 
Should I add this column on the stage of adding data to observable list :

```
while(rs.next()){
    //Iterate Row
     ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
       //Iterate Column
       row.add(rs.getString(i));

         }
        //   System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );
        data.add(row);

     }
```

Or added somehow after? 
I tried this solution but it doesnt work for me.

[How to add CheckBox's to a TableView in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217625/how-to-add-checkboxs-to-a-tableview-in-javafx)

I am a beginner in javafx and I would greatly appreciate your help

Comment: I would recommend to use javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell<S,T> from the link, which you've provided. Another way - use selected items list from selection model, instead of checkBoxes

Comment: That ould work but I have another problem-checkboxes are not binded to the specific rows. So for example if user sets other column alphabetically, rows switch but checkboxes stay in their positions

Comment: checkBox'es selected property can be binded to the dataItems, which corresponds to the rows. So you just need to remove data items from items list, which have selected property true.