# JavaFX TableView with simple xml model

Tags: javafx, tableview, simple-framework

For configuration I use simple xml. I also use this model for TableView. My problem is using of boolean. TableView needs BooleanProperty but simple xml cannot access to this object, obviously. How can I combine this without write big code?

**Model**

```
@Root(name="scriptdata")
@Order(elements={"title", "active"})
public class ScriptData {
    @Element (required=true)
    private String title;
    @Element (required=false)
    private BooleanProperty active;

    /**
     *
     * @param title
     * @param active
     */
     public ScriptData() {
        this.active = new SimpleBooleanProperty(active);
     }


    public boolean isActive() {
        return active.getValue();
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active.set(active);
    }
```

**CellFactory**

```
modulActiveColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("active"));
modulActiveColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(modulActiveColumn));
modulActiveColumn.setOnEditCommit((EventHandler<CellEditEvent>) t -> {
    ((ScriptData) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
      t.getTablePosition().getRow())
      ).setActive((boolean) t.getNewValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is using of boolean. TableView needs BooleanProperty

You're wrong. In fact the `TableView` never gains access to the `BooleanProperty` object stored in the `active` field of it's items.

`PropertyValueFactory` uses reflection to

1. Access a property object by invoking a method with the constructor parameter concatenated with `"Property"`. (This method would be called `activeProperty()` in your case).
2. If the above doesn't work it wraps the value returned by a the getter for the property in a `ObservableValue`. (The name of the getter in this case is `getActive()` or `isActive`).

In your case the `cellValueFactory` does something similar to the following factory

```
modulActiveColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleBooleanProperty(cellData.getValue().isActive()));
```

Using a `boolean` field to store the data achieves exactly the same result in your case. The drawback of this approach is that programatic updates of the property do not trigger an update of the `TableView` and the edits need to be handled manually.

```
@Root(name="scriptdata")
@Order(elements={"title", "active"})
public class ScriptData {
    @Element (required=true)
    private String title;
    @Element (required=false)
    private boolean active;

    /**
     *
     * @param title
     * @param active
     */
    public ScriptData() {
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes the trick. But first I have got Problem that my model does not update when I checked/unchecked because I used setOnEditCommit(). I found solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27407574/7656068

Comment: It is not an answer, only discussion - conversation without any way to solve the problem