# How to load JavaFX checkboxes data in Tableview on action?

Tags: checkbox, tableview

I wanna make a `TableView` where each column contains a checkbox with a specified text, with an `Add` method. Here is the code of my controller class :

```java
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private CheckBox checkFc, checkNc, 
                     checkMspd, checkDupl, 
                     checkGps, checkPw;

    @FXML
    private TableView<users> tableUsers;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<users, String> colFc, colNc, 
                                       colDupl, colMspd, 
                                       colGps, colPw;

    ObservableList<users> listM;

    int index = -1;
    
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    public void AddUsers() {
        conn = mysqlconnect.ConnectDb();
        String sql = "insert into users (fc, nc, dupl, mspd, gps, pw)Values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        
        try {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(4, checkFc.getText());
            pst.setString(5, checkNc.getText());
            pst.setString(6, checkDupl.getText());
            pst.setString(7, checkMspd.getText());
            pst.setString(8, checkGps.getText());
            pst.setString(9, checkPw.getText());
            pst.execute();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "addition was a success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        colFc.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<users,String>("fc"));
        colNc.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<users,String>("nc"));
        colDupl.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<users,String>("dupl"));
        colMspd.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<users,String>("mspd"));
        colGps.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<users,String>("gps"));
        colPw.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<users,String>("pw"));

        listM = mysqlconnect.getDatausers();
        tableUsers.setItems(listM);
    }
}
```

The app works fine but my checkboxes text is visible all the time instead of when being checked. I unsuccessfully tried to find some YouTube videos and look for some answers online, can anybody help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) Don't forget to respect [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions). All declared elements are written in CamelCase, with a lowercase letter for members and methods (`addUsers` instead of `Add_users`, `colDupl` instead of `col_dupl`).

Comment: I think [that request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217625/how-to-add-checkboxs-to-a-tableview-in-javafx) will answer your question.

Comment: i think that request is about making a column of checkboxes, that's not what i am looking for, i have five 5 checkboxes and add button, whenever i click the add button, it shows on my table the text of the boxes that have been checked, the getText method though  it works, it sends the text regardless of the boxes being checked, thats the issue.