# JavaFX 8 CheckBox serialization

Tags: java, javafx, serialization, checkbox, serializable

I have object like

```
class Person extends Human implements Serializable{ //just random example
String name;
CheckBox check;

//other functions with checkbox and name
}
```

and I want to serialize whole CheckBox object.
I found out that it´s not possible for Java FX elements but is there any workaround around that if I want to serialize only one Java FX  object per instance?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: don't use nodes as data (they are not serializable and there is hardly any reason for them to be), here instead use a plain boolean

Answer (score -3, accepted):

original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217625/how-to-add-checkboxs-to-a-tableview-in-javafx)

```
TableColumn<User, CheckBox> userSelected;

userSelected.setCellValueFactory(arg0 -> {
            User user = arg0.getValue();
            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
            checkBox.selectedProperty().setValue(user.isSelected());
            checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((ov, old_val, new_val) -> user.setSelected(new_val));
            return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(checkBox);
        });
    tableView.getColumns().addAll(userSelected);
```

Comment: repeating: it's __wrong__ to have nodes as data! Instead use `TableColumn<User, Boolean>` with cell visualizing the boolean as checkBox (either custom or CheckBoxTableCell)